# Delicious to Xmarks bookmarks migration

Tags: delicious, xmarks

Does anyone succeeded with full migration from [Delicious.com](http://www.delicious.com/) to [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/)?

I've read [it's possible to move 100 most used Delicious bookmarks](http://getsatisfaction.com/foxmarks/topics/is_it_possible_to_import_bookmarks_from_delicious_com#reply_2579651) to Xmarks, but 100 is just a small part of my bookmarks collection.

Any suggestions on **how to migrate full bookmarks collection from Delicious to Xmarks** would be appreciated.

Comment: I gave up when I ran into the 100 limitation.  

I also had no luck with the Google Sync.

I will stick with Delicious.  The Favorite Tags toolbar in Firefox works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Importing all Delicious bookmarks seems to work now.

Go directly to the [import page](https://buy.xmarks.com/delicious.php) or log in, then go to `My Account -> Tools -> Import bookmarks` from Delicious